# Is this the correct section to as about fluid dynamics of small fans?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to design a stator to be 3D printed and applied to a normal computer fan, to increase flow and so on.

I would like to ask (after providing more data) about the expected velocity distribution of the airflow so that I can model the blades accordingly.

Is Engineering.SE the correct place? it looks engineering to me, even if hobbyist.

Comment: This looks to be on-topic here. You will see that there are other questions that involve fans and CFD.